# Change grid-settings programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a XAML-code that looks like this

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition x:Name="primaryColumn" Width="40*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid x:Name="titlepanel">
      ...
   </Grid>
   <Grid x:Name="leftgrid" Grid.Row="1">
      ...
   </Grid>
   <Grid x:Name="rightgrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
      ...
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Is it possible in C# to change the rightgrid so it looks like this

```
<Grid x:Name="rightgrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
   ...
</Grid>
```

I cannot just set in the XAML-code as there are situations, where I need that? 
Or do I have to create a new page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code behind, to unset `RowSpan` on `rightgrid` you'd do:

```
rightgrid.ClearValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty);
```

Similarly, to set the `Row` to 1, you'd do:

```
rightgrid.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
```

From the MSDN:

- [ClearValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597464%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Grid.RowSpanProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowspanproperty%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Grid.RowProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowproperty%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks :D I could not figure out, what DependencyProperty was